# Why is the spring boot actuator not returning "jvm.gc.pause"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a simple spring boot project. I am upgrading the spring version from `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.7.9` to `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:3.0.3:compile` and I seem to be missing the `jvm.gc.pause` metric...

```
15:09:05  Expecting ArrayList:
15:09:05    ["application.ready.time",
15:09:05      "application.started.time",
15:09:05      "disk.free",
15:09:05      "disk.total",
15:09:05      "executor.active",
15:09:05      "executor.completed",
15:09:05      "executor.pool.core",
15:09:05      "executor.pool.max",
15:09:05      "executor.pool.size",
15:09:05      "executor.queue.remaining",
15:09:05      "executor.queued",
15:09:05      "http.server.requests",
15:09:05      "http.server.requests.active",
15:09:05      "jms.connection.count",
15:09:05      "jms.connection.time",
15:09:05      "jms.message-consumer.count",
15:09:05      "jms.message-consumer.messages-received.count",
15:09:05      "jms.message-consumer.time",
15:09:05      "jms.message-producer.count",
15:09:05      "jms.message-producer.messages-sent.count",
15:09:05      "jms.message-producer.messages-sent.time",
15:09:05      "jms.message-producer.time",
15:09:05      "jms.queue.count",
15:09:05      "jms.queue.time",
15:09:05      "jms.session.count",
15:09:05      "jms.session.time",
15:09:05      "jms.temporary-queue.count",
15:09:05      "jms.temporary-queue.time",
15:09:05      "jvm.buffer.count",
15:09:05      "jvm.buffer.memory.used",
15:09:05      "jvm.buffer.total.capacity",
15:09:05      "jvm.classes.loaded",
15:09:05      "jvm.classes.unloaded",
15:09:05      "jvm.compilation.time",
15:09:05      "jvm.gc.live.data.size",
15:09:05      "jvm.gc.max.data.size",
15:09:05      "jvm.gc.memory.allocated",
15:09:05      "jvm.gc.memory.promoted",
15:09:05      "jvm.gc.overhead",
15:09:05      "jvm.info",
15:09:05      "jvm.memory.committed",
15:09:05      "jvm.memory.max",
15:09:05      "jvm.memory.usage.after.gc",
15:09:05      "jvm.memory.used",
15:09:05      "jvm.threads.daemon",
15:09:05      "jvm.threads.live",
15:09:05      "jvm.threads.peak",
15:09:05      "jvm.threads.states",
15:09:05      "logback.events",
15:09:05      "netty.alloc.arena.active.byte.count",
15:09:05      "process.cpu.usage",
15:09:05      "process.files.max",
15:09:05      "process.files.open",
15:09:05      "process.start.time",
15:09:05      "process.uptime",
15:09:05      "spring.security.authorizations",
15:09:05      "spring.security.authorizations.active",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter after",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter before",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.AuthorizationFilter after",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.AuthorizationFilter before",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.DisableEncodeUrlFilter after",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.DisableEncodeUrlFilter before",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.ExceptionTranslationFilter after",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.ExceptionTranslationFilter before",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.HeaderWriterFilter after",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.HeaderWriterFilter before",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.LogoutFilter after",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.LogoutFilter before",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.RequestCacheAwareFilter after",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.RequestCacheAwareFilter before",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter after",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter before",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.SecurityContextHolderFilter after",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.SecurityContextHolderFilter before",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter after",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter before",
15:09:05      "spring.security.filterchains.active",
15:09:05      "spring.security.http.secured.requests",
15:09:05      "spring.security.http.secured.requests.active",
15:09:05      "system.cpu.count",
15:09:05      "system.cpu.usage",
15:09:05      "system.load.average.1m",
15:09:05      "tomcat.sessions.active.current",
15:09:05      "tomcat.sessions.active.max",
15:09:05      "tomcat.sessions.alive.max",
15:09:05      "tomcat.sessions.created",
15:09:05      "tomcat.sessions.expired",
15:09:05      "tomcat.sessions.rejected"]
15:09:05  to contain:
15:09:05    ["jvm.buffer.memory.used",
15:09:05      "jvm.threads.states",
15:09:05      "jvm.memory.committed",
15:09:05      "jms.message-producer.messages-sent.time",
15:09:05      "process.uptime",
15:09:05      "jvm.memory.used",
15:09:05      "jvm.gc.pause",
15:09:05      "jms.connection.time",
15:09:05      "jms.queue.time",
15:09:05      "logback.events",
15:09:05      "jvm.memory.max",
15:09:05      "tomcat.sessions.active.current",
15:09:05      "jvm.buffer.total.capacity",
15:09:05      "jms.queue.count",
15:09:05      "system.cpu.usage",
15:09:05      "jvm.threads.live",
15:09:05      "jvm.classes.unloaded",
15:09:05      "jvm.classes.loaded",
15:09:05      "jvm.threads.peak",
15:09:05      "tomcat.sessions.rejected",
15:09:05      "tomcat.sessions.alive.max",
15:09:05      "jvm.gc.memory.promoted",
15:09:05      "jms.connection.count",
15:09:05      "jvm.buffer.count",
15:09:05      "jms.session.count",
15:09:05      "jms.message-consumer.messages-received.count",
15:09:05      "jms.message-producer.time",
15:09:05      "jvm.gc.memory.allocated",
15:09:05      "jms.message-producer.count",
15:09:05      "tomcat.sessions.expired",
15:09:05      "http.server.requests",
15:09:05      "tomcat.sessions.created",
15:09:05      "jvm.gc.max.data.size",
15:09:05      "jms.message-producer.messages-sent.count",
15:09:05      "system.cpu.count",
15:09:05      "process.start.time",
15:09:05      "jvm.threads.daemon",
15:09:05      "tomcat.sessions.active.max",
15:09:05      "jms.session.time",
15:09:05      "jms.message-consumer.count",
15:09:05      "jvm.gc.live.data.size",
15:09:05      "process.cpu.usage",
15:09:05      "jms.message-consumer.time"]
15:09:05  but could not find the following element(s):
15:09:05    ["jvm.gc.pause"]
```

So it seems to be missing `jvm.gc.pause`

This seems to work in the previous version and is received from the `/actuator/metrics` rest endpoint. Why are these suddenly missing?